# I want to create weights automatically for a CNN in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have tried to create weights automatically using a for loop and a dictionary in python. The problem is that W1 first shape needs to be equal to W2 second shape and so on and I can't find a way to do it. The shape_1 is the output nodes and the shape_2 the input nodes. So W1 output nodes need to be equal to W2 input nodes.

```
def initialize_parameters(NumberOfParameters):
    parameters={}

    for i in range( 1 ,NumberOfParameters):
        shape_1 = 25
        shape_2 = 12288
        parameters['W' + str(i)] = tf.get_variable("W"+str(i),[shape_1, shape_2],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1))
        parameters['b' + str(i)] = tf.get_variable("b"+str(i),[shape_1, 1],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
        shape_2 = shape_1
        shape_1 = shape_1 // 2

    return parameters
```

I receive the following output:

```
#W1 : [25, 12288]
#b1 : [25, 1]
#W2 : [25, 12288]
#b2 : [25, 1]
#W3 : [25, 12288]
#b3 : [25, 1]
```

But the output should look like the following:

```
#W1 : [25, 12288]
#b1 : [25, 1]
#W2 : [25, 12288]
#b2 : [25, 1]
#W3 : [25, 12288]
#b3 : [25, 1]
```

Comment: You are re-initializing shape_1 = 25 and shape_2 = 12288 at the beginning of each for loop. Therefore, shape_2 = shape_1 and shape_1 = shape_1 // 2 are not effective. For the next time, please spend some moments with Python debugger before posting a question on Stackoverflow

Comment: What's the difference between *I receive the following output* and *the output should look like the following*?